# Ajax Help using jquery(uses php and mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using the following code to create a form with submit button and after submitting displays the info in the same form ..the code i have written is

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function get(){
$.post('data.php', { name: form.name.value },
function(output) {
    $('#age').html(output).show();
    $('#number').html(output).show();

}) ;

 }

</script>
</head>
<body> 
<p>
 <form name="form">
   name:
 <input type ="text" name="name"><input type ="button" value ="Get" onclick="get();">
 </form>
<div id="age"></div>
</p>

</body>

 </html>
```

File 2

```
<?php

Connect to DB
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);



if ($name==NULL)
echo "please enter an name!";
else
{   
$age= mysql_query("SELECT age FROM parentid WHERE id ='$name'");
$age_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($age);   
  if ($age_num_rows==0)
  echo "id does not exist";

 else
 {
  $age = mysql_result($age, 0);
  echo "$name's title is $age'";
 }
$number= mysql_query("SELECT number FROM parentid WHERE id ='$name'");
$number_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($number);   
  if ($name_num_rows==0)
  echo "name does not exist";

 else
 {
  $number = mysql_result($number, 0);
  echo "$name's number is $number'";
 }
 }
 ?>
```

The output i am getting is

```
12882's title is xxxx'12882's reportno is Resource id #4'
```

here 12882's title is xxxx is what is in the database and 
12882's reportno is Resource id #4 is not something in the database and i do not know where it is generating the result from

Comment: That's a MySQL resource. Use something like `mysql_fetch_assoc($number)`, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a mysql resource, avoid using `mysql_result`. Use something like these instead

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($age);
echo $name . '\'s title is ' . $row[0];
```